# Zero all filesize in a large directory tree (delete file content, keep files)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, powershell

How can I delete the content (zero the filesize) of a large directory tree (10 GB, 1K files) but keep the entire tree structure, filenames, extensions. (If I can keep the original last write time [last content modification time] that's a bonus).

I have seen several suggestions for individual files, but can not figure out the way to make this work for the entire CWD.

```
def deleteContent(fName):
    with open(fName, "w"):
        pass
```

Comment: is it linux file system ?

Comment: unfortunately not. i know it would be very easy there.

Comment: I would run xcopy.exe with proper parameters (there is one that makes zero length files).

Comment: What's wrong with the method you show, used with something like `os.walk()`?

Comment: How about `get-childitem c:\temp\test\*.* -recurse | clear-content` *(powershell)*? What's LWT? What's CWD?

Comment: `os.walk()` i was unable to make it work.

Comment: LWT last write time, CWD current working directory

Comment: Resetting the Lastwritetime should be doable but that's not a simple oneliner anymore

Comment: @lieven-keersmaekers `get-childitem c:\temp\test\*.* -recurse | clear-content` works, but some files gives me `PermissionDenied ClearContentUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ClearContentCom`. any way I can reset the entire current working directory permission so the code works on all files?

Comment: Run powershell as administrator. Following should retain the LWT. `gci c:\temp\test\*.* | % {    
    $LastWriteTime = $PSItem.LastWriteTime
    clear-content $PSItem;
    $PSItem.LastWriteTime = $LastWriteTime
}`

Comment: thank you: error as; `+ ... .* | % { $LastWriteTime = $PSItem.LastWriteTime clear-content $PSItem ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'clear-content' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`

Comment: That's due to pasting in comments :(. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running following as administrator should reset all content to an empty file and retain the lastwritetime's of the files

```
gci c:\temp\test\*.* -recurse | % {    
    $LastWriteTime = $PSItem.LastWriteTime
    clear-content $PSItem;
    $PSItem.LastWriteTime = $LastWriteTime
}
```

Comment: thanks, getting a number of errors, but made 200MB from 10 GB. errors, `----1----ClearContentUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ClearContentComm 
   and
-----2----

At line:4 char:5
+     $PSItem.LastWriteTime = $LastWriteTime
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
   : ExceptionWhenSetting

-----3-----
+     $PSItem.LastWriteTime = $LastWriteTime
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException`

Comment: Most likely the files are in use. Proper exceptionhandling should be added if this is something you need regulary.

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk()` returns all directories as a list of following tuple:

```
(directory, list of folders in the directory, list of files in the directory)
```

When we combine your code with `os.walk()`:

```
import os

for tuple in os.walk("top_directory"):
    files = tuple[2]
    dir = tuple[0]
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(dir, file), "w"):
            pass
```

Comment: thanks, i am getting the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m:\test\zerofile.py", line 7,
    with open(os.path.join(dir, file), "w"):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'm:\\test\\ktop.ini'`

Comment: Can you try to run the script in cmd which is running as administrator?

Comment: did as admin. same error msg, seemingly at the first file in the dir tree (top most dir's first file).

Comment: Probably another program is using `ktop.ini` file. You can add `try-except` statement to `with open(os.path.join(dir, file), "w"): pass` lines. So the code won't clear content of the files which you don't have permission to access.

Comment: any simple way to reset permission for the entire dir where the code is running?

Comment: Maybe this can work: Disable all auto-start programs in windows and restart your computer. Then, try to run this script again.

Answer (score 1):

All good answers, but I can see two more challenges with the answers provided:

When traversing over a directory tree, you may want to limit the depth it goes to, this to protect you from very large directory trees. And secondly Windows has a limitation (enforced by Explorer) of 256 characters in the filename and path. While this limitation will produce various OS errors, there is a workaround for this.

Lets start with the workaround for the maximum length of the filepath, you can do something like the following as a workaround:

```
import os
import platform


def full_path_windows(filepath):
    """
    Filenames and paths have a default limitation of 256 characters in Windows.
    By inserting '\\\\?\\' at the start of the path it removes this limitation.

    This function inserts '\\\\?\\' at the start of the path, on Windows only
    Only if the path starts with '<driveletter>:\\' e.g 'C:\\'.

    It will also normalise the characters/case of the path.

    """
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        if filepath[1:3] == ':\\':
            return u'\\\\?\\' + os.path.normcase(filepath)
    return os.path.normcase(filepath)
```

There are mentions of write protect, or file in use, or any other condition which may result in not being able to write to the file, this can be checked (without actually writing) by the following:

```
import os

def write_access(filepath):
    """
    Usage:

    read_access(filepath)

    This function returns True if Write Access is obtained
    This function returns False if Write Access is not obtained
    This function returns False if the filepath does not exists

    filepath = must be an existing file
    """
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        return os.access(filepath, os.W_OK)
    return False
```

For setting minimum depth or maximum depth, you can do something like this:

```
import os


def get_all_files(rootdir, mindepth = 1, maxdepth = float('inf')):
    """
    Usage:

    get_all_files(rootdir, mindepth = 1, maxdepth = float('inf'))

    This returns a list of all files of a directory, including all files in
    subdirectories. Full paths are returned.

    WARNING: this may create a very large list if many files exists in the 
    directory and subdirectories. Make sure you set the maxdepth appropriately.

    rootdir  = existing directory to start
    mindepth = int: the level to start, 1 is start at root dir, 2 is start 
               at the sub direcories of the root dir, and-so-on-so-forth.
    maxdepth = int: the level which to report to. Example, if you only want 
               in the files of the sub directories of the root dir, 
               set mindepth = 2 and maxdepth = 2. If you only want the files
               of the root dir itself, set mindepth = 1 and maxdepth = 1
    """    
    file_paths = []
    root_depth = rootdir.rstrip(os.path.sep).count(os.path.sep) - 1
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        depth = dirpath.count(os.path.sep) - root_depth
        if mindepth <= depth <= maxdepth:
            for filename in files:
                file_paths.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        elif depth > maxdepth:
            del dirs[:]  
    return file_paths
```

Now to roll the above code up in a single function, this should give you an idea:

```
import os

def clear_all_files_content(rootdir, mindepth = 1, maxdepth = float('inf')):
    not_cleared = []
    root_depth = rootdir.rstrip(os.path.sep).count(os.path.sep) - 1
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        depth = dirpath.count(os.path.sep) - root_depth
        if mindepth <= depth <= maxdepth:
            for filename in files:
                filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                if filename[1:3] == ':\\':
                    filename = u'\\\\?\\' + os.path.normcase(filename)            
                if (os.path.isfile(filename) and os.access(filename, os.W_OK)):
                    with open(filename, 'w'): 
                        pass
                else:
                    not_cleared.append(filename)
        elif depth > maxdepth:
            del dirs[:]  
    return not_cleared
```

This does not maintain the "last write time".

It will return the `list` `not_cleared`, which you can check for files which encountered a write access problem.

Comment: `dirpath` is fully qualified if `rootdir` is fully qualified, so you should begin with `rootdir = os.path.abspath(rootdir)`. This matters because `u"\\\\?\\"` paths have to be normalized to only use backslash as the path separator. Also, it supports long relative paths, which are also subject to the DOS namespace `MAX_PATH` (260 character) limit. UNC paths have the same limit, so also check for them and rewrite the initial `u"\\\\"` as `u"\\\\?\\UNC\\"`. The filename case is irrelevant on Windows, so there's no point in calling `os.path.normcase`.

Comment: On Windows, `os.access` only checks the read-only attribute -- not security or I/O sharing, so other than read-only files, it's not helping to avoid `PermissionError` exceptions (i.e. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` and `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`). Just try to open the file in a try/except block, and ignore `PermissionError`.

Comment: @eryksun, I really thought that os.access was testing access, in cluding GUI/GID, hence a PermissionError ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED should return False for os.access. Anyway, I will test this and adapt my answer when I get a moment. Thank you for the tip on UNC paths, I will build that into my routine.

Comment: `os.access` just calls `GetFileAttributes` on Windows. The literal way to enhance it would be via `GetSecurityInfo` and `AccessCheck`. But that wouldn't check for shared read, write and delete access, or rights granted by the parent directory (e.g. read file attributes or delete access). A better way would be to try opening a handle via `NtOpenFile` with the requested access (native NT I/O doesn't require backup semantics to open a directory and would allow supporting `dir_fd`), which lets the file system check the security and sharing. There's a bit more to it for edge cases.

Comment: You can `stat` each file to get its last access and modified times (`st_atime` and `st_mtime`), which can be set back after truncating it via `os.utime(filename, (atime, mtime))`. In Python 3 you can rework walking the tree to use `os.scandir` directly instead of `os.walk`. This retains the basic stat info from WinAPI `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`, which in turn saves the cost of calling `stat` on each file.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the in depth. I will certainly update my library of file routines with this. Thanks!